# Summarizing a group header formula field in the footer in Crystal Xi

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, footer

I am trying to put the summarization of a formula that is in the header in the footer. The body of the report is hidden as only the summaries are relevant.

The formula in the header is

```
{@orig_balance}+{rtetable.transactioncalculatedprice}.
```

I only want the first record of the set(which is why I have it in the header). Now I want to summarize these records and have them show in the footer.

I have two headers...the first is accounts and the second is primary ID. I have this formula in the primary id and want it summarized in the accounts.

I have been banging my head against the wall now and need some help....Please

Comment: Two headers means you have two groups? And you want to summarixe the formula that is in group header 1 and group header 2?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to sum the headers in each footer? But the header is just a single value. Or are you trying to sum the hidden body values? Or are you trying to put the sum in the report footer? It could do with a little more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two groups and hence two headers.

1. In group hear1 write below formula `@Reset` and place to left most part.

   ```
   Shared Numbervar Store;
   Store:=0;
   ```
2. In group header1 write below formula `Store` and place to the right of `Reset`:

   ```
   Shared Numbervar Store;
   Store:=<<Group header1 value>>;
   ```
3. In group header 2 `Calculate` write belwo formula:

   ```
   Shared Numbervar Store;
   Store:=Store+<<group header2 value>>;
   ```
4. In group footer `display` write below formula:

   ```
   Shared Numbervar Store;
   Store;
   ```

Let me know if this is not your requirement.